# Checking status of program

Tags: bash

This always works if I just type:`if [ ! "$(pgrep vlc)" ]; then echo not running; else echo running; fi` in the command prompt, but as soon as I make it a script, give it chmod +x and run it I always get "running" as the output. Can someone give me a lead?

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0


if [ ! "$(pgrep vlc)" ]; then echo not running; else echo running; fi
```

Comment: how are you calling that script?

Comment: I think you were right, I was calling the script by the name "checkvlc.sh" and it was registering for me as a process(of course)

Answer (score 2):

If the name of your script contains 'vlc', pgrep founds that script running and condition in if is false, even though real VLC is not running.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert

```
   echo "$(pgrep vlc)"
```

before the `if` stament

Comment: Yep, you pointed me to it, I was calling "checkforvlc.sh" and of course that showed up in the ps list. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can be more selective with your `pgrep` command. It's not necessary to use command substitution and brackets.

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0

if ! pgrep -f "/path/to/vlc " >/dev/null; then echo not running; else echo running; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

another option to avoid mixup with your own script is to use ps's '-C' flag
(I dont know how portable it is though)

```
if ps -C vlc > /dev/null ; then echo running; else echo not runing; fi
```